# Plotting many tuples with ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I have data tuples, and I want to visualize them in an "overview" in a single plot with ListLinePlot.
Example data:

```
data = {{-0.390974, -0.158722}, {-0.0113731, -0.555487}, {-0.336282, -0.711334}, 
        {-0.192636, -0.381761}, {-0.0910332, -0.367015}, {-0.239589, -0.460568}, 
        {-0.149918, -0.522732}, {-0.336194, -0.319426}, {-0.0599809, -0.21935}, 
        {-0.156575, -0.531545}, {1.29412, -0.399341}, {0.568567, -0.328689}, 
        {-0.110572, -0.191875}, {-0.156716, -0.375925}, {1.04408, -0.24397}}
```

Some data goes up (e.g. the first entry), some goes down (the second entry). However, `ListLinePlot[data]` interprets the tuples as x-y-pairs, rather than as 2-entry-time-series. How do I plot that data as many 2-point-lines in a single plot? It works with higher dimensional data (3 entries and more), but not for tuples.

Comment: Try `ListLinePlot[Transpose@data, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @eldo No... that plots 2 long  lines. I want many short lines with just 2 points.

Comment: have a look at `Partition`

Comment: @george2079 I am really interested in the data format that needs to be parsed into ListLinePlot to achieve this easily. I know how to do it if I explicitly supply the two x-coordinates (1,2) for the two data points. Then, the data looks like this: {{{1,x1},{2,y1}},{{1,x2},{2,y2}},...}. I also know how to do this. But that seems like a hack and too complicated. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Perhaps `ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> All]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, that does the trick!!!! Thank you! Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: I see, i didn't understand the question (The answer makes it clear though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When you extend the plot range beyond 2, a horizontal line is drawn using this solution.

Answer (score 3):

A few alternatives:

```
 ListLinePlot[{{1, #[[1]]}, {2, #[[2]]}} & /@ data]

 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{{1, 2}, #}] & /@ data]

 ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[{Last@#2, #} &, data, {2}]]
```